# Drawing polygons with specific heights and widths in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, vector-grid

I have a dataset that defines my plot corners. Within each plot, there are a number of subplots, each with specific dimensions. I need to create polygon shapefiles for each of the subplots.

Is there a way to do this in the ArcGIS GUI?

In other words, I currently have this -

[image]

and I need to generate this -

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: To do this I would use the Create Fishnet tool from the GUI or write geometries from ArcPy.

Comment: Fishnet and a lot of feature creation got me there. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would use [Create Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) a number of times because it:

> Creates a fishnet of rectangular cells. The output can be polyline or
>   polygon features.

These fishnets can have cells wider than high, and higher than wide, to meet your requirements.